# Website not Displaying Properly on Smaller Screens

Tags: html, css, mobile, web-applications, web

I have create a website,On bigger screen it looks good however on small screens like laptop and mobile devices it does not displayed properly, Images and Texts are moved aside each other.I am  really confusing on what is happening.

Need  any advice on this situation?

Comment: We cannot say anything here, since your question is extremely vague. You should add some comparing screenshots, post more details, show your styling rules.

Comment: im a beginner, all i need if you can share your ideas and directs where i should do..

Comment: We'd _love_ to help and give advice and hints. But as said: you need to tell us what is happening. We cannot see over your shoulder, so we have no idea what you actually see. Without that, how do you expect is to help?

Comment: Thanks,i want to paste my website link here but i dont want to go in public yet..would love if you can give me your email address to send and also the coding to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@media` queries are css properties which is used to handle your website on mobile because the screen of mobile is smaller then dekstop so we need to handle it with `@media` queries.

> With media queries you can write different css for different screen sizes to handle you website in all the screen

Read this w3schools brief tutorial about `@media` queries : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your site should be developed as a responsive site.For that you can use @media queries or you can for  framework such as bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

By viewport metatag Website is display according to screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```